# domap resulting on error 'google' is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, delphi, gmlib

I'm make use of GMLib some time ago to create same forms with Delphi 7 that did must interact with google maps.

At time this work great, (begin of year) until now the project stay paused, now I came back to work with him and the code that I was written back in time is not running any more.

For some reason when I run: `GMap.DoMap;`

I did get back a error of javascript with message:

> 'google' is not defined

. This occur in different lines of javascript at different times of execution and at end the program breaks on an exception.

First of all I updated my component to last version (1.2.4) once this is originally written using the 1.1.0, but this not solved my case.

Then I've tryed to find at google anyone with the same problem, but I can't find one solution. So please, if someone could help me on this, thanks.

---

So, sorry for posting this too soon, now that I did test the code on other machine, this run perfectly.

Well, obviously this is not a component problem, but yes a incompatibility, my pc is running Windows 8, and I have a lot of things installed on him, but I will try figure out what is causing this.

Comment: That happens usually because the `google javascript` could not be correctly loaded. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660955/google-is-not-defined-when-using-google-maps-v3-in-firefox-remotely). Maybe some answer there applies to your `gmlib`.

Comment: Can you put the code where you call DoMap method?? Thanks

Comment: let me know your incompatibility, thanks!!

Comment: The problem is not even I know what happend. After some time, and also after a reboot on my machine all worked. My problem now is know what cause this, because on the future I'm not going to crazy with this issue again.