# Why does google maps API not load on firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the v3 of Google Maps API. 
My map loads and everything works fine in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox i get the error "google.maps.Map is not a constructor".

In Chrome or Safari when i enter 'google.maps' in the console I get an complex object with lots of stuff inside of it(including google.maps.Map) but in Firefox i get a much less complete object with only an empty modules object, and a '**gjsload**' and a Load function. I've read that there are issues with firefox and google maps, but it was not fixed when i updated Firefox. 
Does anyone know how i can get the API to load in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with add ons i had. When i restarted firefox in safe mode (no add ons) the map worked. :) I found the answer here: ["google is not defined" when using Google Maps V3 in Firefox remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660955/google-is-not-defined-when-using-google-maps-v3-in-firefox-remotely)

Comment: In my case, it is adblock. Just disable the filter then restart.