# Issue while loading Google maps api V3 in Firefox over https

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-maps-api-3, https

I am loading google maps api v3 script over https using the url 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
.The maps get loaded and work properly in IE and chrome. But on firefox the maps don't work and I can see the error **TypeError: google.maps.event is undefined**
.I checked if the google object is loaded using undefined check and its not getting loaded on Firefox, IE and chrome load it properly.

The same behavior can be checked via the url 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple
. The error occurs only over https and not http. The same issue has been noticed over multiple networks and multiple machines. 
Firefox version being used:- 33.1.

My script import is in the head and my jquery bindings in the document.ready, so not much chance of the scripts executing before the import.
Same behavior is getting exhibited even in Firefox safe mode.

Can somebody help me out with a solution for this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660955/google-is-not-defined-when-using-google-maps-v3-in-firefox-remotely

Comment: have you solved this problem? I have the same

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem would be the ssl, you could try erasing the "s" from http

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: I want to use the functionality over https. Googlemaps does support https, so that should not be problem. Also if https was a problem, it wouldnt work in IE or chrome:)