# Google Maps API not loading. Error Message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In the process of upgrading my Route Tracker app, I have encountered problems associated with Google Maps API not loading resulting in the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined".

I am including the google maps API URL as follows:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```

and the error is generated by the following statement in Javascript:

```
coords = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);
```

This app worked very well before but unfortunately no longer as I suspect google introduced significant changes. I have looked at the answers corresponding to the same error message but so far to no avail.

The javascript code snippets are shown below:

```
function ShowLocation(position) 
{           
    var coords;     
    var markerOptions = {
        map: geolocationClass.map,
            position: coords 
        };

    // Fetch coordinates
    var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

    // Store previous coordinates
    coordinatesClass.lat[distanceTimeClass.counter] = myLat;
    coordinatesClass.lng[distanceTimeClass.counter] = myLong;

    // Google API-ready latitude and longitude
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);  <--- Error here 

    .............

    .............
}
```

The function ShowLocation gets called as follows:

```
function GetLocationUpdate() 
{  
    ..............

    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        geolocationClass.geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
        geolocationClass.watchID = 
            geolocationClass.geoLoc.watchPosition(ShowLocation, 
            ErrorHandler, options);

        ...........
    }
    ............
}
```

Comment: Most likely the geolocation is running/returning before the API has loaded.  You could try using a [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) (which doesn't require the API to be loaded).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Is that the same issue? [google-is-not-defined-when-using-google-maps-v3-in-firefox-remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660955/google-is-not-defined-when-using-google-maps-v3-in-firefox-remotely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being caused by calling the `new google.maps.LatLng` class before the Google Maps JavaScript API is loaded. In the [documentations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) you will see a `callback` in the script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and in script:

```
function initMap() {
   map = new google.maps.Map....
```

This is to make sure that after loading the JavaScript API, `initMap` will execute.

If the `new google.maps.Map` executes before the JavaScript API is loaded successfully it will return the error `google is not defined`. This error is very common even before. The new changes that Google introduced has nothing to do with this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately I have already tried that route many times before without any success. It may still work but only after I have generated a new JavaScript API key to try out for my debug version or at least that's my understanding from the email I have received from Google Cloud Platform support section. I will do this first and then come back with my feedback.

Comment: I Generated a new Maps Javascript API Key and restricted it using HTTP referrers restriction (ie __file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html).

The error is still "Ungaught Reference Error: google is not defined".